# How to delete from a cursor untill the end of a close bracket (bracket is not in the same line of the cursor)

Tags: visual-studio, vim, vscodevim

Sometimes I need to delete from half till end of the scope, how to do that in vim
I know that I can delete everything inside {} with `di{` but I want to delete just half

Here is a ScreenShot for more details:

[image: Code Preview]

or how to dele this part of code:

[image: CodePreivew2]

I tried `V/} Enter n n` till I reach to the parent {} then `d`

I also know that I can do `vt}` if } is in the same line

but I need to select lines until } while it's not in the same line

Answer (score 1):

The notion of "motion" comes from vi but the notion of "text object" came later and, while text objects are for all intent and purpose a special kind of motions, there is no 1-1 relationship to expect between regular, *one-way* motions and special *two-way* text objects. So yes, there is a two-way "inner braces" text object but there is no built-in one-way counterpart.

The classic approach is to:

1. visually select the text object ("scope" is not a Vim concept),
2. go back to normal mode, which leaves the cursor at the end of the desired text object,
3. use the desired operator from the cursor to the last position.

In concrete terms:

```
viB<C-c>d''
```

That is basically the best we have if we constrain ourselves to the built-ins. I think it is fine and gets the job done but you might find it too verbose. If that's the case, one approach would be to make a dedicated pair of visual mode and operator-pending mode mappings:

```
xnoremap EB iB<C-c>v''
onoremap EB <Cmd>normal vEB<CR>
```

which would allow you to do `dEB` to cut the text from the cursor to the end of the "inner braces text" object.

Notes:

- creating mappings that go the other way shouldn't be too hard,
- the formula above is quick and dirty, it will certainly need a bit of work to deal with edge cases,
- one could imagine defining one-way counterparts of all text objects in a for loop for maximum street credibility.

See the sadly under-developed `:help omap-info`, and [this great article](https://vimways.org/2018/transactions-pending/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with search:

```
d/}<Enter>
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but I wonder if there is a faster way, +there may be some other {} scopes, inside the parent scope `d/}<Enter>` only deletes to the first }

Comment: You can press `.` to repeat the last move until you delete to the place you want.